# In Meteor, how do I find a record in a collection given the year, month, day?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

So I have a collection of posts where a JavaScript Date object is stored in the "submitted" field. Given the year/month/day (2015/02/03 for example), I need to be able to pull the records that fit this description.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work. I'm clueless as to the correct syntax:

```
Posts.find({$where : 'return this.submitted.getMonth() == 2 && this.submitted.getDay() == 3 && this.submitted.getYear() == 2015'})
```

Also, is it better for me to just separately store 3 separate variables in the collection to begin with? Like `submitted.year`, `submitted.month`, `submitted.day`. It sounds a lot simpler, but it requires me to add in a whole bunch of fields, which may seem redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) question. The solution is to search within a date range. [Tweak](http://try.mongodb.org/) the query below:

```
Posts.find({submitted: {$gte: new Date('2015-02-23'), $lt: new Date('2015-02-04')}})
```